# having trouble with function and asyncio

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

here is my Code so far:

```
import discord
from discord import Webhook, AsyncWebhookAdapter
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Activity, ActivityType
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)

async def amazon():
  URL = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=gaming"

  with AsyncHTMLSession() as session:
    response = await session.get(URL)
    response.html.arender(timeout=20)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, "lxml")
    results = soup.select("a.a-size-base.a-link-normal.s-link-style.a-text-normal")

    max_price = 10
    
    for result in results:
      price = result.text.split('$')[1].replace(",", "")
      if float(price) < max_price:
        print(f"Price: ${price}\nLink: https://www.amazon.com{result['href'].split('?')[0]}")



@client.command()
async def amaz(ctx):
  await amazon()
  await ctx.send("hello")

      

client.run("iputmytokenhere")
```

here is the error I get when doing $amaz:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'HTML.arender' was never awaited
  response.html.arender(timeout=20)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
C:\Users\CK\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:428: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncHTMLSession.close' was never awaited
  self.close()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I am using this as a fun project, any help is greatly appreciated. I tried many things but nothing seems to be working. I want the bot to send the scraped data to a discord webhook.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

+You can use the following code for the `amazon()` function.

```
async def amazon():
  URL = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=gaming"
  # add the string of the webhook url
  WEBHOOK_URL = "https://your_webhook_url"

  # change the with statement to assignment following the documentation
  session = AsyncHTMLSession()
  response = await session.get(URL)
  # add await to prevent the "was not awaited" error
  await response.html.arender(timeout=20)
  # create the webhook object
  webhook = Webhook.from_url(WEBHOOK_URL, adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))

  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, "lxml")
  results = soup.select("a.a-size-base.a-link-normal.s-link-style.a-text-normal")

  max_price = 10
   
  for result in results:
    price = result.text.split('$')[1].replace(",", "")
    if float(price) < max_price:
      # change print() to webhook.send() to send the data from a webhook
      await webhook.send(f"Price: ${price}\nLink: https://www.amazon.com{result['href'].split('?')[0]}")
```

Comment: Don't simply tell *"use the following code"*, it's useless. Please explain what have you changed in the code in order for it to work.

Comment: +Added explanatory comments for the changes, but anyway if the code works it is not useless at all.